# An opposite result of direction of stack in C using valgrind

Tags: c, stack, stack-overflow

I use valgrind to find out a confused problem of the direction of stack.

See the code below, I want to know why the operator "p1 += 0x80; *p1 = 1" is valid and the operator "p2 -= 0x80; *p2 = 1" is invalid write according to the valgrind?

I think all the variable is alloced in the stack according to the OS, and the it is growing up to the lower address, so I think the "-=" is valid and the "+=" is invalid because it may be large compared to the top of stack which may be not in the stack limits.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int *p1 = &a;
    p1 += 0x80;
    int *p2 = &a;
    *p1 = 1;
    p2 -= 0x80;
    *p2 = 1;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Want to prove Anders is right - I suggest try +/- 2 rather that 0x80 - that should trash something within main :-)

Comment: Just because valgrind doesn't complain about an operation doesn't mean the operation is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add `0x80` to `p1`, you end up with a pointer that points somewhere earlier in the stack frame - likely where the arguments to `main()` or the environment are stored.  This is why Valgrind doesn't warn you - it doesn't know that you're not making a valid access to that part of the stack.

When you subtract `0x80` from `p2`, you end up with a pointer that points below `%esp`.  This part of the stack is logically not allocated yet, which is why Valgrind warns you.

Answer (score 7):

No that code gives undefined behavior.

Your stack consists of an integer, and an integer pointer nothing more.

When you move the pointer 0x80 ints forward in memory (past stack) and write there you have invoked undefined behaviour, you can't put much faith in what happens after that.

It is of course valid to move the pointer there, you can move it anywhere, but not to write there.

Answer (score 0):

First, you gave us code that doesn't even compile.

Then, going 128 positions beyond an object is undefined behavior, whether you go behind the object or in front. In your example your `-= 0x80` should bring you back to the original pointer.

So valgrind should probably be ok with the second, even though your first assignment to `*p` may already have crashed your stack.